# How to deploy updates to Cloud Code via continuous integration?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

We are new to Parse and would like to be able to deploy Cloud Code updates via our CI/CD at the same time as we deploy front end updates.

Is there a standard/recommended way? Or we simply create a custom dockey image `FROM parseplatform/parse-server` and copy our code into the cloud code folder?

Is there a more simple way to do this? Cloud Code deploy API ? or command like with `firebase deploy --only=functions`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Simply clone/fork https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-example

And build your container from that !